# pasar el valor de un input, como valor de clave de un objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript

**Código Javascript: un botón con id=btn y un input con id=name **

```
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("clic",function(){const nom=document.getElementById("name").nodeValue;
const str=nom.toString();let persona = {nombre: str,}console.log(persona.nombre)});
```

Comment: Muestras lo que tienes, pero no mencionas lo que te pasa. Cual es el error que te sale?

Comment: document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click") 

talves te falte la letra K, es click .. prueba.

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto dentro de la funcion:

```
   const nombre=document.getElementById("name").value; 
   const persona = { nombre };
   console.log(persona.nombre);
```

y como mencionaron, debería ser "click" en el .addEventListener